# A lot of intellisense errors after angular 6 upgrade

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2017, angular6

I have about 80ish errors in my visual studio 2017 error list window after upgrading to angular 6. Those errors only appear in VS as ng serve in command line compiles fine and the application works fine.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   TS2339  (TS) Property 'length' does not exist on type '{}'. C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web (tsconfig or jsconfig project)    C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web\src\app\components\pollution\pollution.component.ts   101 Active
Error   TS2415  (TS) Class 'FocusKeyManager<T>' incorrectly extends base class 'ListKeyManager<FocusableOption & T>'.
  Types of property 'setActiveItem' are incompatible.
    Type '(index: number) => void' is not assignable to type '{ (index: number): void; (item: FocusableOption & T): void; }'.
      Types of parameters 'index' and 'item' are incompatible.
        Type 'FocusableOption & T' is not assignable to type 'number'.  C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web (tsconfig or jsconfig project)    C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web\node_modules\@angular\cdk\a11y\typings\key-manager\focus-key-manager.d.ts 19  Active
Error   TS2305  (TS) Module '"C:/Users/anon/Documents/Projects/EEA.Projects/DEP/MassAir/Web/node_modules/rxjs/Observable"' has no exported member 'Observable'. C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web (tsconfig or jsconfig project)    C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web\node_modules\@angular\cdk\collections\typings\data-source.d.ts    8   Active
Error   TS2305  (TS) Module '"C:/Users/anon/Documents/Projects/EEA.Projects/DEP/MassAir/Web/node_modules/rxjs/Subject"' has no exported member 'Subject'.   C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web (tsconfig or jsconfig project)    C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web\node_modules\@angular\cdk\collections\typings\selection.d.ts  8   Active
Error   TS2305  (TS) Module '"C:/Users/anon/Documents/Projects/EEA.Projects/DEP/MassAir/Web/node_modules/rxjs/Observable"' has no exported member 'Observable'. C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web (tsconfig or jsconfig project)    C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web\node_modules\@angular\cdk\layout\typings\breakpoints-observer.d.ts    10  Active
Error   TS2305  (TS) Module '"C:/Users/anon/Documents/Projects/EEA.Projects/DEP/MassAir/Web/node_modules/rxjs/Observable"' has no exported member 'Observable'. C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web (tsconfig or jsconfig project)    C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web\node_modules\@angular\cdk\overlay\typings\overlay-ref.d.ts    11  Active
Error   TS2305  (TS) Module '"C:/Users/anon/Documents/Projects/EEA.Projects/DEP/MassAir/Web/node_modules/rxjs/Subject"' has no exported member 'Subject'.   C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web (tsconfig or jsconfig project)    C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web\node_modules\@angular\cdk\overlay\typings\overlay-ref.d.ts    12  Active
Error   TS2305  (TS) Module '"C:/Users/anon/Documents/Projects/EEA.Projects/DEP/MassAir/Web/node_modules/rxjs/Observable"' has no exported member 'Observable'. C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web (tsconfig or jsconfig project)    C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web\node_modules\@angular\cdk\overlay\typings\position\connected-position-strategy.d.ts   12  Active
Error   TS2305  (TS) Module '"C:/Users/anon/Documents/Projects/EEA.Projects/DEP/MassAir/Web/node_modules/rxjs/Subscription"' has no exported member 'Subscription'. C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web (tsconfig or jsconfig project)    C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web\node_modules\@angular\cdk\scrolling\typings\scroll-dispatcher.d.ts    10  Active
Error   TS2305  (TS) Module '"C:/Users/anon/Documents/Projects/EEA.Projects/DEP/MassAir/Web/node_modules/rxjs/Observable"' has no exported member 'Observable'. C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web (tsconfig or jsconfig project)    C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web\node_modules\@angular\cdk\scrolling\typings\scroll-dispatcher.d.ts    11  Active
Error   TS2305  (TS) Module '"C:/Users/anon/Documents/Projects/EEA.Projects/DEP/MassAir/Web/node_modules/rxjs/Observable"' has no exported member 'Observable'. C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web (tsconfig or jsconfig project)    C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web\node_modules\@angular\cdk\scrolling\typings\scrollable.d.ts   9   Active
Error   TS2305  (TS) Module '"C:/Users/anon/Documents/Projects/EEA.Projects/DEP/MassAir/Web/node_modules/rxjs/Observable"' has no exported member 'Observable'. C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web (tsconfig or jsconfig project)    C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web\node_modules\@angular\cdk\scrolling\typings\viewport-ruler.d.ts   10  Active
Error   TS2305  (TS) Module '"C:/Users/anon/Documents/Projects/EEA.Projects/DEP/MassAir/Web/node_modules/rxjs/Subject"' has no exported member 'Subject'.   C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web (tsconfig or jsconfig project)    C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web\node_modules\@angular\cdk\stepper\typings\stepper.d.ts    12  Active
Error   TS2474  (TS) In 'const' enum declarations member initializer must be constant expression.   C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web (tsconfig or jsconfig project)    C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web\node_modules\@angular\compiler\src\output\output_ast.d.ts 600 Active
Error   TS2474  (TS) In 'const' enum declarations member initializer must be constant expression.   C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web (tsconfig or jsconfig project)    C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web\node_modules\@angular\compiler\src\output\output_ast.d.ts 601 Active
Error   TS2474  (TS) In 'const' enum declarations member initializer must be constant expression.   C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web (tsconfig or jsconfig project)    C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web\node_modules\@angular\compiler\src\output\output_ast.d.ts 602 Active
Error   TS1169  (TS) A computed property name in an interface must directly refer to a built-in symbol. C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web (tsconfig or jsconfig project)    C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web\node_modules\@angular\core\src\render3\interfaces\container.d.ts  35  Active
Error   TS1169  (TS) A computed property name in an interface must directly refer to a built-in symbol. C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web (tsconfig or jsconfig project)    C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web\node_modules\@angular\core\src\render3\interfaces\container.d.ts  40  Active
Error   TS1169  (TS) A computed property name in an interface must directly refer to a built-in symbol. C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web (tsconfig or jsconfig project)    C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web\node_modules\@angular\core\src\render3\interfaces\container.d.ts  45  Active
Error   TS1169  (TS) A computed property name in an interface must directly refer to a built-in symbol. C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web (tsconfig or jsconfig project)    C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web\node_modules\@angular\core\src\render3\interfaces\container.d.ts  50  Active
Error   TS1169  (TS) A computed property name in an interface must directly refer to a built-in symbol. C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web (tsconfig or jsconfig project)    C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web\node_modules\@angular\core\src\render3\interfaces\container.d.ts  58  Active
Error   TS1169  (TS) A computed property name in an interface must directly refer to a built-in symbol. C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web (tsconfig or jsconfig project)    C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web\node_modules\@angular\core\src\render3\interfaces\container.d.ts  79  Active
Error   TS1169  (TS) A computed property name in an interface must directly refer to a built-in symbol. C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web (tsconfig or jsconfig project)    C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web\node_modules\@angular\core\src\render3\interfaces\view.d.ts   50  Active
Error   TS1169  (TS) A computed property name in an interface must directly refer to a built-in symbol. C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web (tsconfig or jsconfig project)    C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web\node_modules\@angular\core\src\render3\interfaces\view.d.ts   56  Active
Error   TS1169  (TS) A computed property name in an interface must directly refer to a built-in symbol. C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web (tsconfig or jsconfig project)    C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web\node_modules\@angular\core\src\render3\interfaces\view.d.ts   66  Active
Error   TS1169  (TS) A computed property name in an interface must directly refer to a built-in symbol. C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web (tsconfig or jsconfig project)    C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web\node_modules\@angular\core\src\render3\interfaces\view.d.ts   68  Active
Error   TS1169  (TS) A computed property name in an interface must directly refer to a built-in symbol. C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web (tsconfig or jsconfig project)    C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web\node_modules\@angular\core\src\render3\interfaces\view.d.ts   70  Active
Error   TS1169  (TS) A computed property name in an interface must directly refer to a built-in symbol. C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web (tsconfig or jsconfig project)    C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web\node_modules\@angular\core\src\render3\interfaces\view.d.ts   79  Active
Error   TS1169  (TS) A computed property name in an interface must directly refer to a built-in symbol. C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web (tsconfig or jsconfig project)    C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web\node_modules\@angular\core\src\render3\interfaces\view.d.ts   87  Active
Error   TS1169  (TS) A computed property name in an interface must directly refer to a built-in symbol. C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web (tsconfig or jsconfig project)    C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web\node_modules\@angular\core\src\render3\interfaces\view.d.ts   94  Active
Error   TS1169  (TS) A computed property name in an interface must directly refer to a built-in symbol. C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web (tsconfig or jsconfig project)    C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web\node_modules\@angular\core\src\render3\interfaces\view.d.ts   103 Active
Error   TS1169  (TS) A computed property name in an interface must directly refer to a built-in symbol. C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web (tsconfig or jsconfig project)    C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web\node_modules\@angular\core\src\render3\interfaces\view.d.ts   109 Active
Error   TS1169  (TS) A computed property name in an interface must directly refer to a built-in symbol. C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web (tsconfig or jsconfig project)    C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web\node_modules\@angular\core\src\render3\interfaces\view.d.ts   111 Active
Error   TS1169  (TS) A computed property name in an interface must directly refer to a built-in symbol. C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web (tsconfig or jsconfig project)    C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web\node_modules\@angular\core\src\render3\interfaces\view.d.ts   113 Active
Error   TS1169  (TS) A computed property name in an interface must directly refer to a built-in symbol. C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web (tsconfig or jsconfig project)    C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web\node_modules\@angular\core\src\render3\interfaces\view.d.ts   115 Active
Error   TS1169  (TS) A computed property name in an interface must directly refer to a built-in symbol. C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web (tsconfig or jsconfig project)    C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web\node_modules\@angular\core\src\render3\interfaces\view.d.ts   122 Active
Error   TS1169  (TS) A computed property name in an interface must directly refer to a built-in symbol. C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web (tsconfig or jsconfig project)    C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web\node_modules\@angular\core\src\render3\interfaces\view.d.ts   131 Active
Error   TS1169  (TS) A computed property name in an interface must directly refer to a built-in symbol. C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web (tsconfig or jsconfig project)    C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web\node_modules\@angular\core\src\render3\interfaces\view.d.ts   137 Active
Error   TS2474  (TS) In 'const' enum declarations member initializer must be constant expression.   C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web (tsconfig or jsconfig project)    C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web\node_modules\@angular\core\src\sanitization\bypass.d.ts   10  Active
Error   TS2474  (TS) In 'const' enum declarations member initializer must be constant expression.   C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web (tsconfig or jsconfig project)    C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web\node_modules\@angular\core\src\sanitization\bypass.d.ts   11  Active
Error   TS2474  (TS) In 'const' enum declarations member initializer must be constant expression.   C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web (tsconfig or jsconfig project)    C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web\node_modules\@angular\core\src\sanitization\bypass.d.ts   12  Active
Error   TS2474  (TS) In 'const' enum declarations member initializer must be constant expression.   C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web (tsconfig or jsconfig project)    C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web\node_modules\@angular\core\src\sanitization\bypass.d.ts   13  Active
Error   TS2474  (TS) In 'const' enum declarations member initializer must be constant expression.   C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web (tsconfig or jsconfig project)    C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web\node_modules\@angular\core\src\sanitization\bypass.d.ts   14  Active
Error   TS1169  (TS) A computed property name in an interface must directly refer to a built-in symbol. C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web (tsconfig or jsconfig project)    C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web\node_modules\@angular\core\src\sanitization\bypass.d.ts   23  Active
Error   TS1169  (TS) A computed property name in an interface must directly refer to a built-in symbol. C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web (tsconfig or jsconfig project)    C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web\node_modules\@angular\core\src\sanitization\bypass.d.ts   31  Active
Error   TS2535  (TS) Enum type 'BypassType' has members with initializers that are not literals.    C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web (tsconfig or jsconfig project)    C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web\node_modules\@angular\core\src\sanitization\bypass.d.ts   31  Active
Error   TS1169  (TS) A computed property name in an interface must directly refer to a built-in symbol. C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web (tsconfig or jsconfig project)    C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web\node_modules\@angular\core\src\sanitization\bypass.d.ts   39  Active
Error   TS2535  (TS) Enum type 'BypassType' has members with initializers that are not literals.    C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web (tsconfig or jsconfig project)    C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web\node_modules\@angular\core\src\sanitization\bypass.d.ts   39  Active
Error   TS1169  (TS) A computed property name in an interface must directly refer to a built-in symbol. C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web (tsconfig or jsconfig project)    C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web\node_modules\@angular\core\src\sanitization\bypass.d.ts   47  Active
Error   TS2535  (TS) Enum type 'BypassType' has members with initializers that are not literals.    C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web (tsconfig or jsconfig project)    C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web\node_modules\@angular\core\src\sanitization\bypass.d.ts   47  Active
Error   TS1169  (TS) A computed property name in an interface must directly refer to a built-in symbol. C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web (tsconfig or jsconfig project)    C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web\node_modules\@angular\core\src\sanitization\bypass.d.ts   55  Active
Error   TS2535  (TS) Enum type 'BypassType' has members with initializers that are not literals.    C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web (tsconfig or jsconfig project)    C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web\node_modules\@angular\core\src\sanitization\bypass.d.ts   55  Active
Error   TS1169  (TS) A computed property name in an interface must directly refer to a built-in symbol. C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web (tsconfig or jsconfig project)    C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web\node_modules\@angular\core\src\sanitization\bypass.d.ts   63  Active
Error   TS2535  (TS) Enum type 'BypassType' has members with initializers that are not literals.    C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web (tsconfig or jsconfig project)    C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web\node_modules\@angular\core\src\sanitization\bypass.d.ts   63  Active
Error   TS2305  (TS) Module '"C:/Users/anon/Documents/Projects/EEA.Projects/DEP/MassAir/Web/node_modules/rxjs/Observable"' has no exported member 'Observable'. C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web (tsconfig or jsconfig project)    C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web\node_modules\@angular\material\autocomplete\typings\autocomplete-trigger.d.ts 14  Active
Error   TS2305  (TS) Module '"C:/Users/anon/Documents/Projects/EEA.Projects/DEP/MassAir/Web/node_modules/rxjs/Observable"' has no exported member 'Observable'. C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web (tsconfig or jsconfig project)    C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web\node_modules\@angular\material\chips\typings\chip-list.d.ts   15  Active
Error   TS2305  (TS) Module '"C:/Users/anon/Documents/Projects/EEA.Projects/DEP/MassAir/Web/node_modules/rxjs/Subject"' has no exported member 'Subject'.   C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web (tsconfig or jsconfig project)    C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web\node_modules\@angular\material\chips\typings\chip.d.ts    11  Active
Error   TS2305  (TS) Module '"C:/Users/anon/Documents/Projects/EEA.Projects/DEP/MassAir/Web/node_modules/rxjs/Subject"' has no exported member 'Subject'.   C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web (tsconfig or jsconfig project)    C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web\node_modules\@angular\material\core\typings\common-behaviors\error-state.d.ts 11  Active
Error   TS2305  (TS) Module '"C:/Users/anon/Documents/Projects/EEA.Projects/DEP/MassAir/Web/node_modules/rxjs/Observable"' has no exported member 'Observable'. C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web (tsconfig or jsconfig project)    C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web\node_modules\@angular\material\core\typings\common-behaviors\initialized.d.ts 9   Active
Error   TS2305  (TS) Module '"C:/Users/anon/Documents/Projects/EEA.Projects/DEP/MassAir/Web/node_modules/rxjs/Observable"' has no exported member 'Observable'. C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web (tsconfig or jsconfig project)    C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web\node_modules\@angular\material\core\typings\datetime\date-adapter.d.ts    9   Active
Error   TS2305  (TS) Module '"C:/Users/anon/Documents/Projects/EEA.Projects/DEP/MassAir/Web/node_modules/rxjs/Subject"' has no exported member 'Subject'.   C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web (tsconfig or jsconfig project)    C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web\node_modules\@angular\material\core\typings\datetime\date-adapter.d.ts    10  Active
Error   TS2305  (TS) Module '"C:/Users/anon/Documents/Projects/EEA.Projects/DEP/MassAir/Web/node_modules/rxjs/Subject"' has no exported member 'Subject'.   C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web (tsconfig or jsconfig project)    C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web\node_modules\@angular\material\core\typings\option\option.d.ts    1   Active
Error   TS2305  (TS) Module '"C:/Users/anon/Documents/Projects/EEA.Projects/DEP/MassAir/Web/node_modules/rxjs/Subject"' has no exported member 'Subject'.   C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web (tsconfig or jsconfig project)    C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web\node_modules\@angular\material\datepicker\typings\datepicker-intl.d.ts    1   Active
Error   TS2305  (TS) Module '"C:/Users/anon/Documents/Projects/EEA.Projects/DEP/MassAir/Web/node_modules/rxjs/Observable"' has no exported member 'Observable'. C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web (tsconfig or jsconfig project)    C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web\node_modules\@angular\material\dialog\typings\dialog-ref.d.ts 11  Active
Error   TS2305  (TS) Module '"C:/Users/anon/Documents/Projects/EEA.Projects/DEP/MassAir/Web/node_modules/rxjs/Observable"' has no exported member 'Observable'. C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web (tsconfig or jsconfig project)    C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web\node_modules\@angular\material\dialog\typings\dialog.d.ts 5   Active
Error   TS2305  (TS) Module '"C:/Users/anon/Documents/Projects/EEA.Projects/DEP/MassAir/Web/node_modules/rxjs/Subject"' has no exported member 'Subject'.   C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web (tsconfig or jsconfig project)    C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web\node_modules\@angular\material\dialog\typings\dialog.d.ts 6   Active
Error   TS2305  (TS) Module '"C:/Users/anon/Documents/Projects/EEA.Projects/DEP/MassAir/Web/node_modules/rxjs/Subject"' has no exported member 'Subject'.   C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web (tsconfig or jsconfig project)    C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web\node_modules\@angular\material\expansion\typings\expansion-panel.d.ts 13  Active
Error   TS2305  (TS) Module '"C:/Users/anon/Documents/Projects/EEA.Projects/DEP/MassAir/Web/node_modules/rxjs/Observable"' has no exported member 'Observable'. C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web (tsconfig or jsconfig project)    C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web\node_modules\@angular\material\form-field\typings\form-field-control.d.ts 8   Active
Error   TS2305  (TS) Module '"C:/Users/anon/Documents/Projects/EEA.Projects/DEP/MassAir/Web/node_modules/rxjs/Observable"' has no exported member 'Observable'. C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web (tsconfig or jsconfig project)    C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web\node_modules\@angular\material\icon\typings\icon-registry.d.ts    4   Active
Error   TS2305  (TS) Module '"C:/Users/anon/Documents/Projects/EEA.Projects/DEP/MassAir/Web/node_modules/rxjs/Subject"' has no exported member 'Subject'.   C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web (tsconfig or jsconfig project)    C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web\node_modules\@angular\material\sort\typings\sort-header-intl.d.ts 9   Active
Error   TS2305  (TS) Module '"C:/Users/anon/Documents/Projects/EEA.Projects/DEP/MassAir/Web/node_modules/rxjs/Subject"' has no exported member 'Subject'.   C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web (tsconfig or jsconfig project)    

C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web\node_modules\@angular\material\sort\typings\sort.d.ts 11  Active
    Error   TS2305  (TS) Module '"C:/Users/anon/Documents/Projects/EEA.Projects/DEP/MassAir/Web/node_modules/rxjs/Subject"' has no exported member 'Subject'.   C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web (tsconfig or jsconfig project)    C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web\node_modules\@angular\material\stepper\typings\stepper-intl.d.ts  1   Active
    Error   TS2307  (TS) Cannot find module 'rxjs-compat/Observable'.   C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web (tsconfig or jsconfig project)    C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web\node_modules\rxjs\Observable.d.ts 1   Active
    Error   TS2307  (TS) Cannot find module 'rxjs-compat/Subject'.  C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web (tsconfig or jsconfig project)    C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web\node_modules\rxjs\Subject.d.ts    1   Active
    Error   TS2307  (TS) Cannot find module 'rxjs-compat/Subscription'. C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web (tsconfig or jsconfig project)    C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web\node_modules\rxjs\Subscription.d.ts   1   Active
    Error   TS2345  (TS) Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'. C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web (tsconfig or jsconfig project)    C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web\src\app\components\lookup\lookup.component.ts 68  Active
    Error   TS2345  (TS) Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'. C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web (tsconfig or jsconfig project)    C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web\src\app\components\monitor\monitor.component.ts   76  Active
    Error   TS2345  (TS) Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'. C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web (tsconfig or jsconfig project)    C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web\src\app\components\parameter\parameter.component.ts   76  Active
    Error   TS2339  (TS) Property 'length' does not exist on type '{}'. C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web (tsconfig or jsconfig project)    C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web\src\app\components\pollution\pollution.component.ts   110 Active
    Error   TS2345  (TS) Argument of type '{

}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'. C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web (tsconfig or jsconfig project)    C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web\src\app\components\rule\rule.component.ts 89  Active
Error   TS2345  (TS) Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'. C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web (tsconfig or jsconfig project)    C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web\src\app\components\rule\rule.component.ts 99  Active
Error   TS2345  (TS) Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'. C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web (tsconfig or jsconfig project)    C:\Users\anon\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web\src\app\components\site\site.component.ts 125 Active
```

Comment: try to install "Angular 6 Snippets " and "Angular Language Service" extensions.

Comment: It seems these extensions are for VS Code. I am using VS 2017, I have always had the functionality from the above extensions. It's just not behaving as expected anymore.

Comment: Some of the errors seem to come from old rxjs 5 imports. Update your imports to rxjs 6. You can use: https://github.com/reactivex/rxjs-tslint

Comment: I have already done the rxjs lint. The errors you referred to, if you look closely, are coming from angular cli and not from my project.

Comment: have you deleted `node_modules` and run npm install / yarn install again?

Comment: Yep. I have tried that a few times.

Answer (score 2):

It is a typescript versioning issue, you may resolve it by changing Typescript version in project properties. Install Typescript 3.0.1.

Right click on the project node in Solution Explorer
Click Properties

Go to the TypeScript Build tab

Change TypeScript version to the desired version or "use latest available" to always default to the newest version installed.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
"typescript": "3.0.1"
```

And select: *Use latest available into TypeScriptBuild*.

I work on **VS2017**.