# Angular build error in core/src/render3/interfaces

Tags: visual-studio-2017, angular6

While building an Angular 6 app i get a compile error in `@angular/core/src/render3/interfaces` on line 35. The line is:

```
   [ACTIVE_INDEX]: number | null;
```

and the error is:
`error TS1169: A computed property name in an interface must directly refer to a built-in symbol.`

I an using `@angular/core@6.1.6`. Am I doing something wrong or is this an Angular bug?

Answer (score -1):

Verify that [Visual Studio is targeting the correct version of Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32385087/vs2015-change-typescript-version) (as seen in your package.json), then try deleting your `node_modules` folder, and rerunning `npm install`.

I believe that this is caused by running Angular 6 with an earlier, incompatible version of typescript (<2.7), because it looks like the ability used by the `container.d.ts` file (referenced in your error) to use *Constant-Named Properties* was added in [Typescript 2.7](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#constant-named-properties). Of course, if it were that simple then `ng serve` would tell you about the Typescript incompatibility, so I assume that I'm either wrong, or that your environment is playing tricks on you.

[See here for a related question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51846265/a-lot-of-intellisense-errors-after-angular-6-upgrade)